# how to parse the xml from this url

Tags: jquery, xml, api, get

I'm making an api call:

```
$.get( "http://gd2.mlb.com/components/game/mlb/year_2015/month_06/day_21/gid_2015_06_21_pitmlb_wasmlb_1/boxscore.xml", function( data ) {
    console.log( data );
});
```

But what I get back in the console is:

```
#document
```

When I drill down under #document in the console, I get my xml data. How do I drill down in jquery, though?

```
console.log(data.#document); //doesn't work
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what works:

```
$(data).find('batting').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr("team_flag"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the data returned is an `XMLdocument` and all `console.log()` is doing is outputting the type of object it is. You either need to parse the `data` as an XML document or convert it to a jQuery object (like `$(data)`) and then interact with it like a normal DOM object.